# How do I get all text from all cells to one variable?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large range that I need to find all numbers that is between four and six digits long.
I know I can use regex for this but I don't want to loop each cell and check them all.

What I need is kind of selecting the range copy and paste in notepad and copy back to a variable.
This way I can regex the variable and find all matches at once.
I don't need to know where the number was found, I just need the numbers.

Is there any way to copy the values to a string like this?

```
Dim text As String
text = ActiveSheet.Range("C9:IQ56").Value
```

is not compatible datatypes.
If I use variant I get an array of the columns and cells.

My attempt to join the array is not successful either.

```
text = ActiveSheet.Range("C9:IQ56").Value
textstring = ""
For i = 1 To UBound(text, 1)
    textstring = textstring & " " & Join(text(i))
Next i
```

Any help with this?

Comment: Also if you have Office 365, Excel now has `TEXTJOIN` as a worksheet function. `=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,C9:IQ56)`

Comment: But `text` is two dimensional.

Comment: I suspect if you read the cells into a vba variant array (one line of code) and then loop through the array elements with your regex code (or even with `Instr` depending on how complex your pattern is), that your speed will improve considerably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use Application Index to do each row at a time:

```
text = ActiveSheet.Range("C9:IQ56").Value
textstring = ""
For i = 1 To UBound(text, 1)
    textstring = textstring & " " & Join(application.Index(text,i,0))
Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in your code, the declaration and the dimensions of the variable. Here is what you can do:

```
Dim Text() As Variant
Text = ActiveSheet.Range("C9:IQ56").Value

textstring = ""
For i = 1 To UBound(Text, 1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(Text, 2)
        textstring = textstring & " " & Text(i, j)
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: If I need to loop every value like this then it's not much difference to looping the sheet? Or is it? I was hoping for something that would be quicker than looping every value.

Comment: @Andreas looping a memory array will be magnitudes quicker than looping a range in a sheet.  Every reference to the the sheet slows down the code.

Comment: @Scott ok thanks. Will try both methods in about an hour.

Comment: @Andreas doubt you will find much difference in time between the two.  Both will be pretty quick.

Answer (score 1):

**Similar approach with delimiters concatenating row strings after loop**

Added a `Timer` and the feature to use separators (delimiters) as well for rows (e.g. "|") as for columns (e.g. ","). Furthermore I demonstrate a way to join all row strings at once *after loop* via `Application.Transpose()` just for the sake of the art, though this isn't faster nor slower than @Scott Craner 's valid solution :+).

**Code**

```
 Sub arr2txt()
   Const SEPROWS As String = "|"        ' << change to space or any other separator/delimiter
   Const SEPCOLS As String = ","        ' << change to space or any other separator/delimiter
   Dim v
   Dim textstring As String, i As Long

   Dim t As Double: t = Timer            ' stop watch
   v = ActiveSheet.Range("C2:E2000").Value  ' get data into 1-based 2-dim datafield array
   For i = 1 To UBound(v, 1)
       v(i, 1) = Join(Application.Index(v, i, 0), SEPCOLS)
   Next i
   textstring = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Index(v, 0, 1)), SEPROWS)
   Debug.Print Format(Timer - t, "0.00 seconds needed")
 End Sub
```